# How can I ask Solr for a field which is either empty or has a distinct value

Tags: solr, lucene

I need to get all documents where field 'status' is either empty or has the value 'active'

I tried

```
status:active OR (NOT status:*)
status:active OR (NOT status:[* TO *])
status:(active OR NOT *)
```

All of these variants don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
-status:[* TO *] OR status:active
```

Comment: Unfortunately, zero results. Each of the terms works as expected, but when combined with OR, it looks like they are combined with AND in fact.

Comment: Hmm... maybe (-status:[* TO *] OR status:active)?

Comment: Tried this too, doesn't work. I will probably amend the field at index time so that it is not empty.

Comment: The above query is correct though. Not sure why it is not working for you. e.g. q=-status:[* TO *] OR status:active. The fields should be indexed and it should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query.

```
-(status:['' TO *] OR -status:active)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick (ref. https://stackoverflow.com/a/35633038/13365):

```
status:active OR (*:* NOT status:["" TO *])
```

I never got the `-status` versions to work.